# HiddenField not returning a value

Tags: flask-wtforms

I cannot find out why this code works with `StringField`, but not with `HiddenField`. The variable `date2` was added just for debugging the issue.

(*Actually, I can leave StringField there, but it took me some time to find the problem and I would like to understand what is wrong in order not to repeat the mistake*)

Form definitions:

```
DAYS = 10
class _OneDayForm(Form):
    alarmtime = StringField(validators=[Optional(), validate_time])
    date2 = StringField()  # json encoded [Y,M,D]
    date = HiddenField()  # json encoded [Y,M,D]

class _PerDayForm(Form):
    days = FieldList(FormField(_OneDayForm), min_entries=DAYS)
    submit = SubmitField()
```

Jinja2 template:

```
    <input name="{{ subform.date.name }}" type="hidden" value="{{ ymd }}">
    <input name="{{ subform.date2.name }}" type="hidden" value="{{ ymd }}">
```

Generated HTML:

```
    <input name="days-0-date" type="hidden" value="[2016, 12, 7]">
    <input name="days-0-date2" type="hidden" value="[2016, 12, 7]">
```

`StringField date2` returns its value, but `HiddenField date` does not. I tried to swap them to be sure that `StringField` vs. `HiddenField` really is the only difference.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, I have found the bug:

I was using `{{ subform.hidden_tag() }}` to display the CSRF token, but it does more than this (and I was not knowing it):

> If your form has multiple hidden fields, you can render them in one
>   block using hidden_tag().

So my hidden field was rendered twice and the first one had no value.

Comment: Same with Flask-Admin!